# printf not printing in C

Tags: c, printf

I am having this simple issue of printf not printing and I can't figure out whether the code is wrong or it's something that the compiler doesn't like or something else. For those of you familiar with the C programming language book, this is my attempt at solving exercise 1-8.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int blanks, tabs, newlines;
    int c;
    blanks = 0;
    tabs = 0;
    newlines = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ')
        ++blanks;
    
        if (c == '\t')
            ++tabs;

        if (c == '\n')
            ++newlines;
        }

    printf("Blanks: %d \n Tabs: %d \n Newlines: %d \n", blanks, tabs, newlines);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, I'm using cc in WSL if anyone was wondering about the setup

Comment: The program works, when I redirect a file as input. So what *does* happen? You could try `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf`. What was your input?

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: You need to input a file, because you use ```EOF```

Comment: You can also input from the keyboard, ending it with Ctrl-D (Linux) or Ctrl-Z (Windows).

Comment: Oh, i was just typing it and pressing enter, now it works with ctrl+D, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`getchar` among other stdin-related functions reads from standard input. Just like most things in C, it's a synchronous (or more aptly "blocking") call, meaning it will wait for *something* to read.

Unlike higher level libraries you might be familiar with (e.g. in Python), C doesn't come stock with a bunch of stream manipulation functions.

Instead, when you read from stdin, you need to actually provide it with something or else the call to `getchar` will have no choice but to wait for something.

Your shell (bash, sh, fish, zsh, cmd.exe, whatever) has made the decision to allow manual text input (via the TTY), instead of closing stdin off and making the program fail. This is why your program hangs indefinitely - it's waiting for *you* to do something since you did not provide the *shell* anything to pipe into stdin instead.

The universally accepted (though by no means only) way to signal the EOF when in this interactive mode is Ctrl-D (one some systems, Ctrl-Z is the EOF sequence). This tells the *shell* to indicate an EOF to the program currently consuming stdin, and thus your program will get `TRUE (1)` for the comparison against EOF (or `FALSE (0)` in this case since you negated it with `!=`).

Hence why it hangs. Your code hasn't even reached the printf statement yet :)